# I want to bind the html id into a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS and JavaScript and understand it better, so please bear with me.

I have a directive that I would like to bind with the id of the div in the index.html, right now I have hard-coded the $scope.name into the controller.
I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Also, since I might be making multiple directives, can I move the controller outside of the directive instead of repeating myself for all the directives?

mydirective.js

```
angular.module('myModule.directive', []).
directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = 'John Smith';
        }],
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/box.html'
    };
}])
```

index.html:

```
<div>Information
    <div id="name1" my-directive></div>
    <div id="name2" my-directive></div>
    <div id="name3" my-directive></div>
</div>
```

Partial:

```
<div class="box-for-person">
    <!-- I want to use the html id here-->
    <div class="name-text">{{ name }}</div> 

</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [isolated scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile):

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myModule.directive', []).
directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          name: '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{name}}</div>'
    };
}]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'Jorge';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div my-directive data-name="foo"></div>
```